# How do I inline an icon and some text and a within a div using Pug?

Tags: html, templates, pug

Say I have the following HTML that I'd like to implement using Pug:

```
<div class="person"><i class="icon person"></i>{{ name1 }}</div>
<div class="person"><i class="icon person"></i>{{ name2 }}</div>
<div class="person"><i class="icon person"></i>{{ name3 }}</div>
```

There are several of these in a row, so I want to inline the tags. If I use this Pug template:

```
.person: i.icon.person {{ name1 }}
.person: i.icon.person {{ name2 }}
.person: i.icon.person {{ name3 }}
```

Then the HTML output becomes:

```
<div class="person"><i class="icon person">{{ name1 }}</i></div>
<div class="person"><i class="icon person">{{ name2 }}</i></div>
<div class="person"><i class="icon person">{{ name3 }}</i></div>
```

where the `<i>` wraps the name, which is undesired. If I split the template into multiple lines, then it gives me the output I want:

```
.person
  i.icon.person
  | {{ name1 }}
.person
  i.icon.person
  | {{ name2 }}
.person
  i.icon.person
  | {{ name3 }}
```

But now it takes 9 lines instead of 3.

Is there any way of inlining the tags so that it's only 1 line per `.person` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my limited understanding, this is not possible with the pug syntax. But, as HTML can be written along with pug, I think the below serves the purpose.

```
.person: <i class="icon person"><i>{{ name1 }}
.person: <i class="icon person"><i>{{ name2 }}
.person: <i class="icon person"><i>{{ name3 }}
```

Or even a better, shorter way,

```
- var foo = '<i class="icon person"><i>'

.person: !{foo}{{ name1 }}
.person: !{foo}{{ name2 }}
.person: !{foo}{{ name3 }}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Gibin's answer, this is another compact way to write it:

```
each name in ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
  .person: <i class="icon person"><i>{{ name }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the better approach :)